# Graph Classes Containing Complete Multipartite Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

For example, I was wondering about graph classes that contain complete multipartite graphs. I thought of cographs, which are more generally included in comparability graphs, and then Perfect graphs.

What would some further examples of well-known graph classes that include complete multipartite as a special case be?

I can think connected graphs, and hamiltonian graphs, so what would further examples of classes that include complete multipartite and their complements? Obviously this rules out connected/hamiltonian.

Comment: Every edge ($K_2$) is a complete multipartite graph, so I guess your question should be a bit more specific.

Comment: Do you mean the other way around?  I mean, what are some classes that complete multipartite graphs belong to?  Because all the classes you name are such classes, but do not contain complete multipartite graphs.